# Global ignore support in TFVC

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Is it possible to have a global ignore file configured in TFVC. Similar to e.g. git can be configured to have a ~/.gitignore file and configure it as a global ignore file for all projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using local workspaces you can use a .tfignore that follows the same format as .gitignore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155786.aspx

Update: The exact usecase is not supported by TFVC as seen in the comments.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just as with git you need to put `.gitignore` into every project root (git repository).

So with TFVC you need to put `.tfignore` in every solution root.

You can put `.tfignore` into the root of of TFVS repository, but from my experience I cannot tell if it will take effect when it is not checked out into local repository.